# Javascript - variable in object

Tags: javascript, object, tealium

Given that I have the following script, how can I append/use varible `portVal` in the object i.e `"investment_value": portVal`

> ```
>   var portVal = 100000
>   setTimeout(invalidForm, 2000);
>     function invalidForm() {
>       utag.link({
>           "event_name": "invalid form submission",
>           "investment_value": portVal,
>           "page_title": "Calculator - Invalid form submission",
>           "error_message": "Mandatory fields",
>           "language":   "en",
>           "country":    "Test",
>           "segment":    "Test",
>           "sub_segment":"Test"
>       });
>   }
> ```

How do I `console.log` that object's `investment_value`?

Comment: Is your attempt not working in some way?

Comment: It appears that is not coming up, what would be the correct way?, or how can I console log that object's investment value.

Comment: Maybe portVal is undefined or your code isn't being executed?  I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: so this is correct  "investment_value": portVal, it doesnt require any '"'+portVal+'" stuff like that?

Answer (score 0):

You have a tealium tag there.

Tealium is a TMS. Which changes things.

Tealium has its own concept of variables. Data Layer variables. window.utag_data is the object containing the DL variables for tealium. Therefore, if the portVal is declared and set via Tealium ui, you're supposed to access it like so: window.utag_data.portVal

But all this can be easily checked in the console. No need to deploy Tealium's code and try debugging it before local console debugging.

There's another issue with TMSes. The timing. Let's assume the portVal is just a global var, so, window.portVal. But it may be declared later in the pageload/render process than it's being accessed from Tealium. This can (and should) be debugged through breakpoints, but really, you can just debug it in the tealium object using something like typeof portVal rather than portVal in case breakpoints feel intimidating.